# Lambda expression to for each loop

Tags: java, lambda

I would like to know how do I convert the following lambda expression to a for-each loop:

```
private static List<GrantedAuthority> mapToGrantedAuthorities(List<Authority> authorities) {
    return authorities.stream()
            .map(authority -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority.getName().name()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Because Im using JAVA 1.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That should work:

```java
List<GrantedAuthority> list = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
for(Authority auth : authorities)
    list.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(auth.getName().name()));
return list;
```

I guess you are using java lower than 1.8, that's why you want to do that, it's probably faster too.

Answer (score 0):

The basis of Lambda Expressions is that the Lambda takes a class with  one method only, in this case it is doing a foreach loop with the stream, and is creating a new SimpleGrantedAuthority using the name from the list being passed in and then returning another list of authorities.

So it is taking a list of Authorities and returning the same List but as GrantedAuthorities.

```
List<GrantedAuthority> granted = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
for( Authority auth : authorities)
{
    granted.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(auth.getName().name()));
}
return granted;
```

Comment: May be I am just misunderstanding the first sentence of your answer, but Lambda Expressions can take an arbitrary number of parameters.

Comment: Sorry i didnt make myself clear, Most simple Lambda calls rely on Functional Interfaces, a functional interface has exactly one abstract method. - i confused methods and parameters, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Google Guava (https://github.com/google/guava) to get somewhat closer to the Java 8 style in previous Java versions:

```
private static List<GrantedAuthority> mapToGrantedAuthorities(final List<Authority> authorities) {
    return Lists.transform(authorities, new Function<Authority,GrantedAuthority>(){
        @Override
        public GrantedAuthority apply(Authority authority) {
            return new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority.getName().name());
        }
    });
}
```